# MySQL cursor done only 1 loop

Tags: mysql, function

I have this MySQL Function with loop and csalculating time

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE type VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE cas DATETIME DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE starttime DATETIME DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0;
 
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT type,date from log WHERE nick = name AND (type = 'connect' OR type = 'disconnect') AND date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY id ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
OPEN cur;
label: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO type,cas;
    SET total = total + 1;/*only for testing number of loops*/
    IF type = 'connect' THEN
            SET starttime = cas;
    END IF;
        IF type = 'disconnect' THEN
            SET total = total + (cas-startime);
        END IF;

    IF done = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE label;
    END IF;
END LOOP label;
CLOSE cur;
  
RETURN total;
```

END
And After usage:

```
select GetGameTimeFromMonth('ATomas');
```

Result is: 1

Bud query have thousands of rows...

Comment: This is not a valid function - there is no return variable or returns statement - please add create statement.

Answer (score -4):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE type VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE cas DATETIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE starttime DATETIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT type, date FROM log WHERE nick = name AND (type = 'connect' OR type = 'disconnect') AND date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY id ASC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
    label: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO type, cas;
        SET total = total + 1; /* only for testing number of loops */
        
        IF type = 'connect' THEN
            SET starttime = cas;
        END IF;

        IF type = 'disconnect' THEN
            SET total = total + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, cas);
        END IF;

        IF done = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE label;
        END IF;
    END LOOP label;

    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN total;
END
```

try this code

Comment: Please explain why this might work bearing in mind that indentation is not a thing in sql.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.